# Ambiguous reference to function error when compiling

Tags: fortran, overloading

So I have a fortran .f90 file (part of the Monte-Carlo tool called SWEEP) that basically contains two main modules for the implementation of a variable length list using two types. The two modules are as follows:

```
Module LIST_DP_T
Implicit None
Public

Type LIST_DP
    Integer :: Count = 0
    Double Precision, Pointer :: Items(:)
End Type

Interface Assignment(=)
    Module Procedure SetP
End Interface

Interface Operator(+)
    Module Procedure Add
    Module Procedure AddItem
    Module Procedure AddItems
End Interface

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Destroy(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Clears memory associated with a list type.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: list

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    list%Count = 0
    Deallocate(list%Items, STAT=err)
    Nullify(list%Items)
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine SetP(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Assigns the list of one list type to another
    !   by passing the list pointer.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items => old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Copy(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Copies the list of one list type to another.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items = old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function Add(list1, list2) Result (sumlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds together two list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list1
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list2
    Type(LIST_DP) :: sumlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: items(list1%Count+list2%Count)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list1%Count > 0) items(1:list1%Count) = list1%Items
    If (list2%Count > 0) items(list1%Count+1:) = list2%Items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(sumlist%Items, STAT=err)
    sumlist%Count = list1%Count + list2%Count
    Allocate(sumlist%Items(sumlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    sumlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItem(list, item) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds a number to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Double Precision, Intent(IN) :: item
    Type(LIST_DP) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: items(list%Count+1)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) items(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    items(list%Count+1) = item

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + 1
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItems(list, items) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds some numbers to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Double Precision, Intent(IN) :: items(:)
    Type(LIST_DP) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Double Precision :: allitems(list%Count+Size(items))

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) allitems(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    allitems(list%Count+1:) = items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + Size(items)
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = allitems
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Double Precision Function SumList(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Returns the sum of the list items.
    Type(LIST_DP), Intent(IN) :: list
    SumList = Sum(list%Items)
End Function

End Module
```

and the other module which is for an integer list:

```
Module LIST_INT_T
Implicit None
Public

Type LIST_INT
    Integer :: Count = 0
    Integer, Pointer :: Items(:)
End Type

Interface Assignment(=)
    Module Procedure SetP
End Interface

Interface Operator(+)
    Module Procedure Add
    Module Procedure AddItem
    Module Procedure AddItems
End Interface

Contains

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Destroy(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Clears memory associated with a list type.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: list

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    list%Count = 0
    Deallocate(list%Items, STAT=err)
    Nullify(list%Items)
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine SetP(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Assigns the list of one list type to another
    !   by passing the list pointer.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items => old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Subroutine Copy(new, old)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Copies the list of one list type to another.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(INOUT) :: new
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: old

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.
    new%Count = old%Count
    new%Items = old%Items
End Subroutine

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function Add(list1, list2) Result (sumlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds together two list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list1
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list2
    Type(LIST_INT) :: sumlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: items(list1%Count+list2%Count)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list1%Count > 0) items(1:list1%Count) = list1%Items
    If (list2%Count > 0) items(list1%Count+1:) = list2%Items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(sumlist%Items, STAT=err)
    sumlist%Count = list1%Count + list2%Count
    Allocate(sumlist%Items(sumlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    sumlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItem(list, item) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds a number to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Integer, Intent(IN) :: item
    Type(LIST_INT) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: items(list%Count+1)

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) items(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    items(list%Count+1) = item

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + 1
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = items
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Function AddItems(list, items) Result (newlist)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Adds some numbers to the end of the list and
    !   returns a new list.

    ! ARGUMENTS.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN)    :: list
    Integer, Intent(IN) :: items(:)
    Type(LIST_INT) :: newlist

    ! VARIABLES.
    Integer :: err = 0
    Integer :: allitems(list%Count+Size(items))

    ! EXECUTABLE CODE.

    ! Save current list.
    If (list%Count > 0) allitems(1:list%Count) = list%Items
    allitems(list%Count+1:) = items

    ! Resize list.
    Deallocate(newlist%Items, STAT=err)
    newlist%Count = list%Count + Size(items)
    Allocate(newlist%Items(newlist%Count), STAT=err)

    ! Assign back the list.
    newlist%Items = allitems
End Function

! -------------------------------------------------------

Integer Function SumList(list)
    ! DESCRIPTION
    !   Returns the sum of the list items.
    Type(LIST_INT), Intent(IN) :: list
    SumList = Sum(list%Items)
End Function

End Module
```

and a third module to make things easier when using the modules:

```
Module LIST_T
    Use LIST_DP_T
    Use LIST_INT_T
    Implicit None
    Public
End Module
```

The module LIST_T is then called from in a different module called Profile_Driver_Input located a different .f90 file  (profile_driver_input.f90) as follows:

```
Module Profile_Driver_Input
Use LIST_T
Use Sweep
Implicit None
Public

Integer, Parameter :: UIN = 102
Integer, Parameter :: MAX_POINTS=1000, MAX_VARS=200

Type Settings
    ! Control parameters.
    Logical :: Solve=.True., PostProcess=.True.
    ! Input files.
    Character(LEN=200) :: MechFile=""  ! Particle mechanism file name.
    Character(LEN=200) :: ChemFile=""  ! Chemistry profile file name.
    ! Time stepping variables.
    Type(LIST_DP)  :: Times  ! Times between PSL outputs (first entry is start time).
    Type(LIST_INT) :: Steps  ! Steps between output times.
....
The code then continues to declare more variables and subroutines.
```

Upon compilation, the following error appears at the end of the Profile_Driver_Input module:

```
Error: Name 'additem' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'additem' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'setp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'setp' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'setp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'setp' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'additem' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'additem' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'setp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'setp' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'setp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'setp' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'additem' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'additem' from module 'list_dp_t'
Error: Name 'setp' at (1) is an ambiguous reference to 'setp' from module 'list_dp_t'
```

I cannot seem to figure out how to resolve this issue. Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Be aware that Code Blocks is only a text editor, it is pretty much irrelevant. If you believe that the compiler may be relevant, which is not unreasonable, you have to tell us the name of the compiler that compiles the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple symbols that are named the same way. They come from different modules, but it is still a problem. For example, a subroutine named `additem` exists in both modules you show.

If you do not actually need to call the subroutines themselves and you only want to call the overloaded operators (`+`) and assignments (`=`), you can change the default accessibility from `public` to `private` inside the module and only leave `public` what actually needs to be accessible.

If both `additem` and `destroy` and other subroutines will need to be accessible from both modules at the same time, you will have to rename them to be unique. For example: `additem_list_int` and `additem_list_dp`.